# Macbook M1- Installation did not complete successfully. see the IDE log for details - Android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

The installation did not complete successfully. see the IDE log for details - Android studio

NDK 21.0.6113669 not install on macbook m1.

Comment: Did my answer helped? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code in your `build.gradle(:app)`:

```
android {
      ndkVersion "21.4.7075529"
  }
```

After that download the [Mac App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) and you will be fine.

Comment: op said he used NDK version 21.0.6113669, but you give example 21.4.7075529. Is that mistype?

Comment: You can use also other version. I just provided the version that I tested. Thanks for the question